# using same ascx control twice while using Register (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using Register at the top of the page to register an ascx control, now the thing is I want to use this control twice on the page.

Now, the problem is when I hit buttons of one instance of the control, it fires the validation of both of the controls, and it obviously breaks, because it should be validating only one control - itself!  The reason I am sure about this is because if I keep only one instance of the control on the page, then it flows nicely.

What I already tried that did **NOT** work:
1)Putting the two instances in different ASP Panels. 
2)Registering the control twice at top of the page, so each registration has only one instance on the page.

I would not like to modify the validation of the control itself, but it's a huge project and it is being used at other places, and I do not want to disrupt other things.  FYI It's using "**Page.IsValid**" to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ValidationGroup property of the validators and the ValidationGroup property of the buttons dynamically in the Page_Load method of the user control.  You can use the user control's ID property as part of the ValidationGroup to differentiate between the two controls.

e.g.,

```
myRequiredValidator.ValidationGroup = "valGroup_" + this.ID;
myButton.ValidationGroup = "valGroup_" + this.ID;
```